# Passing arguments bundle to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to pass some variable from activity to fragment inside a tab layout. I found there are 2 preferred ways of passing argument bundles to the fragment by its initialization methods for the tab layout.

1. By creating static `newInstance()` method and providing details.
2. Creating instance of fragment inside `FragmentPagerAdapter`

But, I have some doubts how this works.

If I create this this is:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    MyFragment myFragment;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("id", id);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
    }

    // ... 
 }
```

Here I am creating the instance of fragment and setting its argument afterwords.

And if I create it in `newInstance()` method something like this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String id) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("id", id);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

Some doubts:

1. When will the `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` will be called? What if after line `new MyFragment()` and before setting bundle?
2. Is there any possibility where `getArguments` can return null?
3. In both ways I am doing the same thing. Setting `args` after `new MyFragment()` call. How late I can set the arguemnts. Is it necessary to set arguments exactly after the `new MyFragment()` call?

Sorry, if I asked some silly question. But I am new to Fragments. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to set arguments twice. Use `newInstance` to instantiate the fragment: `myFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(id);`

Comment: @bigdestroyer I am not setting argument twice. I am asking what will a good method to initialize fragment with agruments

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then you should use the static method way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreate() and onCreateView() will be called sometime after you've committed the fragment transaction. i.e. called commit(). And you set bundle before that.

As long as you're setting bundle before commit, getArguments shouldn't be null.

Both are doing the same thing. In 1st you're creating the fragment instance by yourself and setting bundle yourself. In 2nd you're using what is called a factory method (Effective Java Item 2) which is managed by your fragment. So it's difficult to make mistake in 2nd as arguments are always set.

Comment: Hi gitter. Thanks for the input. It is really helpful. I am using it in `FragmentPagerAdapter`. So it will be useful to create in NewInstance as I will not be sure when `FragmentPagerAdapter` will commit the fragments?

Comment: See the example here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html
Your transaction will be committed sometime after the getItem method is called which returns a Fragment. Since you're creating fragment in constructor of your SectionsPagerAdapter, using either way should work. Using newInstance is less error prone though. Also, instantiate your fragment in getItem instead of constructor, like the example.

Comment: I understood most of the problems! Thanks